# Jquery animate function won't loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm really new to jquery, and javscript in general.  I'm trying to have the .downarrow image appear when #order is hovered.  .downarrow should then slide downward, disappear, and then the whole thing should repeat as long as the user's mouse is still on #order.  There might be something obvious I'm missing, but any help would be much appreciated!

Here's my CSS Rules:

```
.start_info {
    float:left;
    margin-top: 150px;
    width: 176px;
}
.start_text {
    font-family: "glegoo";
    font-size: 36px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #555;
}
.downarrow {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="start_button_container">
<div class="flip-container" id="order">
    <div class="flipper" >
        <div class="front">
            <img src="../../imgs/howto/order.png" >
        </div>
        <div class="back">
        <img src="../../imgs/howto/order1.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="start_info" id="order_info">
    <img src="../../imgs/howto/order_down.png" class="downarrow">
    </div>
</div>
```

And Here's the script:

```
<script>
$( "#order" ).mouseenter(function() {
    function loop() {
        $( ".downarrow" ).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, { queue: false, duration: 300 })
        .delay(600);
        $( ".downarrow" ).animate({
            marginTop: '+=20'
        }, { queue: false, duration: 600 })
        $( ".downarrow" ).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
        $( ".downarrow" ).css({marginTop: "20px"})
    }
    loop();
});
</script>
```

Comment: All that `downarrow` animation can be chained together to reduce the calls to jQuery. `$('.downarrow').animate( {settings} ).delay(600).animate( {settings} ).animate( {settings} ).css( {marginTop: "20px"} );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you're using jQuery so you probably want a solution in that direction, but I think you can do it more easily and elegantly using CSS animations (apologies for the prefixes):

the CSS:

```
.anim{
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-name: arrowdown;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes arrowdown{
    from {
        top: -100px;
        opacity: 1;
    }   
    to {
        top: -10px;
        opacity: 0;
    } 
}
```

the Javascript:

```
var butt = document.getElementById('orderbutton');
var arr = document.getElementById('downarrow');

butt.onmouseover = function(){ 
                       arr.className += " anim"; 
                       arr.style.display = "block"; 
                   }

butt.onmouseout = function(){
                       arr.className -= " anim";
                       arr.style.display = "none"; 
                   }
```

*The `top` values in the animation are just for the example*

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88azmm58/)

The idea is to create a nested image in the button which has your arrow but is hidden (`display: none`) by default. This way, your `top` value is relative to the button itself (don't forget to set `position: absolute` on the image). Then create an animaion that has a keyframe at the top and at the bottom, where the arrow fades out. Set the iterations to infinite and then set the proper event handlers through Javascript (jQuery or otherwise).

I feel this is much simpler than trying to do Javascript animation which, in jQuery, can be slow and cumbersome (although Javascript animation *can* be fast, it's usually for cases where you have heavy animation - this is too simple to justify javascript animation imho).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, The JS Fiddle isn't working for me though.  I'll try plugging it in to my code.

Comment: Just kidding, I realized I'm in chrome instead of Firefox.  the fiddle is working just fine.  That's really cool!  I'm going to try that!  Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisPatty Nice! If your problem is solved, remember to accept an answer once you're satisfied with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()` function, you can read about it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

so your JS code should be:

```
<script>
$( "#order" ).mouseenter(function() {
    function loop() {
        $( ".downarrow" ).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, { queue: false, duration: 300 })
        .delay(600);
        $( ".downarrow" ).animate({
            marginTop: '+=20'
        }, { queue: false, duration: 600 })
        $( ".downarrow" ).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
        $( ".downarrow" ).css({marginTop: "20px"})
    }
    setInterval(loop, 1200);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tooschee answer points in the right direction, though i assume you need to clear the loop from repeating once you leave #order, so

```
<script>
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    var order_animation,
        order_loop = function() {
            //downarrow animation
        };

    $("#order").mouseenter(function() {
        order_animation = setInterval(order_loop, 1200);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        clearTimeout(order_animation);
    });

});
</script>
```